# How do I change my default browser in git's BASH shell?

Tags: git

For some reason, when I try to look at git help pages, it opens them in gedit instead of in chrome, how do I configure it to launch chrome again? I am using git's bash console in windows 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with `git config --global web.browser chrome`.

From the manual:

> The web browser can be specified using the configuration variable
>   help.browser, or web.browser if the
>   former is not set. If none of these
>   config variables is set, the git
>   web--browse helper script (called by
>   git help) will pick a suitable
>   default. See git-web--browse(1) for
>   more information about this.

Comment: Note, for Chromium on Ubuntu you'll need `chromium-browser`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

Setting web.browser and help.browser did not work for me.

What did work was going into the Win-8 control panel and setting the file types associated with Chrome.  I had Notepad++ associated with html files.  (I had a nice image to post for a visual but I don't have the points to upload an image here yet.)

Answer (score 1):

That's right way to set:

```
git config --global web.browser chrome
```

But sometimes it doesn't help, so try a little other browser identifier:

```
git config --global web.browser google-chrome
```

In my case it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The [issue 187](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=258&can=1&q=help&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Owner%20Summary) is similar to your problem, and reports an issue with:

Chrome browser
and/or html association files:
You can try [Doug Knox's "HTM/HTML Associations"](http://dougknox.com/xp/file_assoc.htm) registry fix

Comment: I don't think it's a similar issue, their problem are the spaces in the path under Windows that cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by set chrome as default app in: Windows Control Panel -> programs -> defaults ->  setting.